# Error while rendering action from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my todo list app , I have the following code in my ListsController:

```
 def create
  @list= current_user.lists.build(params[:list])
  if @list.save
    flash[:notice]= "New List created"
    redirect_to controller: "pages",action: :home
  else
   render 'pages/home'
  end
end
```

pages/home.html.erb

```
 <% if signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'home_signed_in' %>
 <% else %>
   <%= render 'home_not_signed_in' %>
<% end %>
```

The "home_signed_in.html.erb" and "home_not_signed_in.html.erb" are present in the pages directory. So when the list I try to create doesnt get saved , this code gets executed in ListsController:

```
 else
   render 'pages/home'
  end
```

And the following error gets thrown :

```
Missing partial lists/home_signed_in, application/home_signed_in with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/lnreddy/my_rails_projects/todo_app/app/views"
```

Why is it not searching in the pages/ folder ? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `render` in your controller does not render that action, it renders that *view*.

You are rendering `pages/home` within the context of the ListsController, so when that view looks for the partial 'home_signed_in', it looks within the folder of the current controller, which is the lists controller (and the lists folder).

If you want to make sure that view renders the partial from the same folder, prefix it with the folder name, eg. 'home/home_signed_in'. Or if the partial is going to be shared across multiple controllers, move it to the application folder (all views fall back to reading from this folder, as the error message lists).

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials for a bit more information on partials.

Comment: Thanks a lot..thats what I suspected.